# Django-imagekit: how to reduce image quality with a preprocessor_spec?

Tags: django, image, image-processing, photologue, django-imagekit

I've created this simple model class, with a Preprocessor to reduce my
photos'quality (the photos'extension is .JPG):

```
from django.db import models
from imagekit.models import ImageModel
from imagekit.specs import ImageSpec
from imagekit import processors

class Preprocessor(ImageSpec):
    quality = 50
    processors = [processors.Format]

class Picture(ImageModel):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures')

    class IKOptions:
        preprocessor_spec = Preprocessor
```

The problem : pictures' quality are not reduced.
Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your example using the latest checkout from the django-imagekit project page and it worked just fine. I lowered the quality to 10 and the difference was obvious. Are you still having issues with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://github.com/burgalon/plupload-s3mixin uses plupload, allows Flash image resizing, and integrates nicely with on-the-fly thumbnail generation