# Resizing image on upload with django-imagekit

Tags: django, imagekit, django-imagekit

I am using imagekit to handle custom size of uploaded images. While it works fine for creating custom size images with this, I'd like to use imagekit to resize the **original image** on upload. Is this possible?

Comment: trying this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460328/django-imagekit-how-to-reduce-image-quality-with-a-preprocessor-spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the link above.

- Create processors as you like for original image (resize, enhance, etc). Look imagekit wiki for examples

  ```
  class ResizeOriginal(processors.Resize): 
      width = 640 
      height = 480
  ```
- Create your ImageSpec for this original image with those previously processors. Leave pre_cache as default (false)

  ```
  class Original(ImageSpec): 
      processors = [ResizeOriginal]
  ```
- Add that ImageSpec to your IKoptions ImageModel preprocessor.

  `preprocessor_spec = Original`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the updated answer is [ProcessedImageField](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/blob/eb801d75f55c6fbea58809c78837f205f237481e/imagekit/models.py#L350).

Reference taken from [@matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927906/django-imagekit-processing-the-original-image).