# Django Imagekit processing the original image

Tags: python, django, imagekit, django-imagekit

With version 1.1 I don't understand how I can preprocess the original image (by JUST using imagekit)

https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/blob/develop/README.rst

Having a model like this:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
   original = models.ImageField(etcetera)
   thumbnail = ImageSpec(etcetera)
```

How do I for instance resize the original image? This was possible in previous imagekits, however the documentation insinuates I need another modelfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ProcessedImageField`:

```
from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField

class Photo(models.Model):
    original = ProcessedImageField(etcetera)
```

There is [in-code documentation](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/blob/eb801d75f55c6fbea58809c78837f205f237481e/imagekit/models.py#L350) on this class, but it looks like it's not being picked up by [readthedocs](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)' autodoc module right now.

I reopened [a bug](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/issues/56) to fix the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking here: https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/blob/master/imagekit/processors/resize.py it looks like the `Fit` class is what you're after.

Untested but I suspect it's something like:

```
from django.db import models
from imagekit.models import ImageSpec
from imagekit.processors import resize

class Photo(models.Model):
    original_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    thumbnail = ImageSpec([resize.Fit(50, 50)], image_field='original_image',
            format='JPEG', options={'quality': 90})
```

Comment: No thats just a processor for the thumbnail.. I want to resize the original image on upload.. this used to be possible with a pre processor in previous django imagekits.. Ofcourse I can use some custom PIL processing, but I'd be surprised if it isn't possible by just using imagekit..

Comment: Sorry about that. I understand what you're asking now. Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845000/resizing-image-on-upload-with-django-imagekit or is it this methodology that you're saying no longer works?

Answer (score 0):

Below will do what you are looking for. You can add other processors to the list of processors as well.  The processors are run prior to saving the image.

```
from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFit

class Photo(models.Model):
    original = ProcessedImageField(
        upload_to='images/%Y%m',
        format=JPEG,
        processors=[ResizeToFit(200, 100)],
        options={'quality': 90}
    )
```